# How to play haptic feedback even when wrist is down?

Tags: swiftui, apple-watch

i'm making a sort of timer on my watch that will vibrate after x amount of minutes. Here is what I have so far:

```
if timerIsGoing && Date().timeIntervalSince(startTime) >= 120.0 {
       self.timer.upstream.connect().cancel()
       timerIsGoing.toggle()
       WKInterfaceDevice.current().play(WKHapticType(rawValue: 4)!)
}
```

My problem is that when my wrist is down the haptic feedback doesn't fire right away because of some power-saving function built-in to the watch software. How can I get it to ignore wrist position and fire off when it's supposed to.

Comment: Background time is very limited. You need to have and be using one of the available “Background Modes”

Comment: i'm looking that up now. thank you